# Configuring Java/Camel/AMQ with route-specific DLQs

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, dead-letter

Java 8/Camel 2.19.x/AMQ 5.15.x here.

I have a Java app that uses Camel to consume messages off of AMQ queues, process those messages, and do stuff with them. Sometimes the output of a route is putting the processing result back up on another queue for further downstream processing, but not always/necessarily. Typical Java/Camel/AMQ setup.

Each of my routes (I'm using the Camel XML DSL) has a configured `<onException>` handler, which typically looks like this:

```
<onException useOriginalMessage="true">
  <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>

  <redeliveryPolicy logStackTrace="true"/>

  <handled>
    <constant>true</constant>
  </handled>

  <log message="${exception.stacktrace}" loggingLevel="ERROR"/>

  <rollback markRollbackOnly="true"/>

</onException>
```

So pretty simple: log the exception and rollback.

What I would like to do is, as part of this `<onException>` handler, to place the **original message** (that failed and caused the exception to be thrown, **not** the exception!) on a route-specific *DLQ* (by "DLQ" I mean just a queue where failed messages can be sent for auditing/reporting/playback purposes)

Meaning, if my app has 30 routes that each consume from 30 different AMQ queues, I would have 30 different "DLQs" where each of their respective `<onException>` handlers would send the failing messages to.

Ideally I'd like this configuration to be on the AMQ side (again perhaps inside of `activem.xml` or similar) so that I don't need to make code changes or redeploys if the DLQ destinations need to change. But if its only possible to do from inside the Camel route/configs, that's fine too.

I *suppose* I could modify each route to contain its own customized destination DLQ for the original messages:

```
<onException useOriginalMessage="true">
  <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>

  <redeliveryPolicy logStackTrace="true"/>

  <handled>
    <constant>true</constant>
  </handled>

  <log message="${exception.stacktrace}" loggingLevel="ERROR"/>

  <rollback markRollbackOnly="true"/>

  <to uri="activemq:fizzbuzz.dlq"/>

</onException>
```

But I'm hoping for something more elegant than this...

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this way will be better for you:

```
             DeadLetterChannelBuilder errorHandlerBuilder = deadLetterChannel("jms:dummy");
    errorHandlerBuilder.onPrepareFailure(exchange -> {
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelJmsDestinationName",exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSDestination",String.class).concat(".DLQ"));
    });

    from("jms:input1")
            .to("seda:process");

    from("jms:input2")
            .to("seda:process");

    from("jms:input3")
            .to("seda:process");

    from("seda:process").errorHandler(errorHandlerBuilder)
            .process(exchange -> {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            });
```

You can compute DLQ queue name in runtime. DeadLetterChannelBuilder can be configured like your onException as well.

Comment: Thans @c0old (+1) - thats an interesting solution...real quick though, whats the differences between the `JmsDestination` header and the `CamelJmsDestinationName` header? Thanks again!!!

Comment: According JMS documentation "When a message is received, its JMSDestination value must be equivalent to the value assigned when it was sent.".  CamelJmsDestinationName is using for dynamically computed queue name during sending. JmsProducer will use value in this header for sending instead of specified in endpoint.

Comment: After testing queues look like [this](https://image.ibb.co/eH7C1p/2018_09_27_16_45_39.png) .

"queue://input1" is value of JMSDestination header (according to "input1" consumer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure in the ActiveMQ itself, you can also add a specific `policyEntry` and use wildcards in the `deadLetterStrategy` like in this example:

Create a dedicated DLQ for all *INBOUND* queues:

```
<policyEntry queue="*.INBOUND.>">
    <deadLetterStrategy>
        <individualDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" queuePrefix="" queueSuffix=".DLQ" useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
    </deadLetterStrategy>
</policyEntry>
```

In that case, I catch the error of the consumer in all my inbound queues:

```
XXX.INBOUND.AAA        -> XXX.INBOUND.AAA.DLQ
YYY.INBOUND            -> YYY.INBOUND.DLQ
ZZZ.INBOUND.BBB.CCC    -> ZZZ.INBOUND.BBB.CCC.DLQ
```

But

```
NNN.MMM.INBOUND        -> ActiveMQ.DLQ
```

as the pattern `*` does not match the dot `.` character in `NNN.MMM`.

You can adjust your pattern to your use-case.

This is very useful for managing consumers not catching properly the exceptions and this is done at ActiveMQ level.